# Nodejs, Socket.io and Sockets in Flash

Tags: flash, sockets, node.js

i'm trying to connect my flash application to my nodejs server running socket.io. To connect via web-browser is no problem.
Now the problem, when the socket-server isn't running i get an IOError in Flash what seams alright. Now when i start the server and try to connect again, i don't get an error, but the socket-server doesn't receive a connection either?!

Thanks

Comment: can you post some code to show us what you are doing. did you remember to add a listener to the connect event?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm not sure socket.io was really designed to talk to arbitrary Flash applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are giving enough information here to get proper help.  I also think someone is right to mention that socket.io is not what you would be using if your frontend/client is flash.  I'm under the impression that socket.io is a library that abstracts socketing in general for HTML5/javascript clients (using any "method" it is able to connect sockets/find based on the browser/setup the client is using).

In order to help, you'd have to show us your node.js socket server code, how you are handling the crossdomain.xml policy file, and also how you are handling the connection of the sockets on the flash end with actionscript.  Good luck!

Comment: I think there's an [Actionscript port](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO) for Socket.IO (7.0.x).